# How to make the unactive item in carousel smaller than the active one

Tags: carousel

[Here is my current Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpVqN.png)

I want to make my left and right item on carousel smaller on the one on the center(active-item). I currently have no idea of how can I achieve that. Thanks

Comment: provide some code about how your carousel looks like

Comment: It was just a normal bootstrap carousel. And I put the 3 items on 'active' div, just like this:

<div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
       <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
       <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
</div>